# Scrolling issue in IOS

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have div which is in absolute position and it is always on top, but the height will vary depends on the content, the scrolling issue occurs when the absolute div's height is more than the body's height.

It stucks the scrolling because it waits for the body to scroll first and then the absolute, or it can happens reversely. it is working in all android devices smoothly but issue with IOS devices.

How can I solve this issue.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: please share the codepen or jsfiddle link .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0uyvt682/ This is an example, please check it whenever you start scrolling from down to top. it stucks a moment with the elastic effect in IPHONE

Answer (score 0):

Try below css:

```
html {
   height:100%;
}
body {
   height:100%;
   overflow:auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```